# Can't get username of last follower from array

Tags: php, json, twitch

Trying to get the name of the latest Twitch-follower with help from a snipper I found online. However I get an error message which I can't understand

```
$json_array2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'.strtolower($channelName).'/follows?limit=1'), true);

$latestFollower = $json_array2['follows']['user']['name'];
```

Typing in the URL in my broser I get this so I'm thinking follows->user->name should be right but I guess not :(

```
    {
    "follows": [
        {
            "created_at": "2014-07-09T23:30:59Z",
            "_links": {
                "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/username17376/follows/channels/sodapoppin"
            },
            "user": {
                "_id": 65845277,
                "name": "username17376",
                "created_at": "2014-07-08T03:59:16Z",
                "updated_at": "2014-07-08T04:14:14Z",
                "_links": {
                    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/username17376"
                },
                "display_name": "Username17376",
                "logo": null,
                "bio": null,
                "type": "user"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_total": 339627,
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=0",
        "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows?direction=DESC&limit=1&offset=1"
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Have you tried var_dump on $json_array2?

Comment: I noticed there is an extra `\`` sign at the end of `$latestFollower = ...` if that's not a paste typo...

Comment: Error Message: Notice: Undefined index: user in /www/webvol1/us/zceajrrm9zgpy1w/public_html/twitch.php on line 304

Comment: The extra ` was a typo in the post.

Comment: `Follows` is an array of objects, this ones index is `0`. A simply `print_r()` or `var_dump()` would've shown that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
$json_array2['follows'][0]['user']['name'];
```

Based on your JSON

```
{
    "follows": [
        {
```

Which shows that `follows` is an array.  The first object in the the array (index 0) is an object that has the property "user"